# How to use boolean functions to display different "menus" of processing game

Tags: boolean, refactoring, processing

I am writing code for a version of "Flappy Bird". I am trying to produce a start menu, end menu, and difficulty menu. So far I have been successful with the start and end, but am struggling with the difficulty menu to show. I believe my code is also very messy and would like to tidy it up, but not sure where to start.

I tried adding boolean "diff" and including that as false in my arguments in the mousePressed method.

```
void mousePressed() {

  //START MENU
  if (menu==true&&end==false) {
    if (mouseX > 175 && mouseX < 625 && mouseY > 500 && mouseY < 600)      {
      menu = false;
      end = true;    
    }
    if (mouseX > 175 && mouseX < 625 && mouseY > 650 && mouseY < 750) {
      diff();
    }
  }

  //GAMEPLAY
  if (menu==false&&end==true) {
    b.bounce();
  }

  //END MENU
  if (menu==false&&end==false) {
    if (mouseX > 200 && mouseX < 600 && mouseY > 500 && mouseY < 600) {
      restart();
      b.bounce();
    }
    if (mouseX > 200 && mouseX < 600 && mouseY > 650 && mouseY < 750) {
      startMenu();
    }
  }
}
```

I expected the output to show the difficulty menu, but it only showed the difficulty menu for one frame, then snapped back to the start menu.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your `diff()` function draws the difficulty menu. I'm also assuming you have a `draw()` function that draws things depending on your game's current state (menu, game, end menu, etc...).

The problem is that you're drawing your difficulty menu once, when the mouse is pressed on the difficulty button, and then it's being immediately overdrawn by `draw()`.

In programs that draw continuously (like with `draw()`), whenever you want to show something for more than one frame, you need to draw it each frame (i.e. in `draw()`).

The solution is to add a "difficulty menu" state. Your `draw()` function would then work something like this:

```
void draw() {
    if (menu && !diff && !end) {
        drawMenu();
    } else if (!menu && diff && !end) {
        diff();
    } else if (!menu && !diff && end) {
        //Why do you draw the game when end is TRUE?
        drawGame();
    } else if (!menu && !diff && !end) {
        //Why do you draw the end menu when end is FALSE?
        drawEndMenu();
    }
}
```

You would, of course, need to modify the `mousePressed()` function as well.

---

You also said that you feel your code is messy. This is a type of **code smell**; Whenever somethings feels "wrong" when you're programming, it often means there's a better way to do it. It's good that you noticed this.

- Firstly, your function names are a bit non-descriptive: Instead of `diff()`, I recommend something like `drawDiffMenu()`. Rule of thumb: Function names should almost always be verbs.
- Secondly, you shouldn't be handling gamestate with a bunch of booleans; Since you can only have one state at a time, you should only have one variable. (If you ever need a state-inside-a-state, make another variable.) Best way to do that is with [enums!](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Example:

```
enum GameState {
    MENU, GAME, DIFF_MENU, END
}
GameState gameState = GameState.MENU;

//...

void draw() {

    // Google "java switch statement"
    if (gameState == GameState.MENU) {
        drawMenu();
    } else if (gameState == GamesState.DIFF_MENU) {
        drawDiffMenu();
    } else if...
    // Etc...
}
```

A nitpick: Calling `b.bounce()` after `restart()` is a bit odd, since in theory that bounce should be a part of your game starting.

Happy coding!